# can not resolve plugin org.jetbrains.android

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Following line in plugin.xml 
`<depends>org.jetbrains.android</depends>` throws an error: can not resolve plugin org.jetbrains.android

As per the post [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206107809-Android-Studio-Plugin-SDK), I added android.jar file (/sdk/platforms/android-25/android.jar) to classpath of IDEA SDK. (File -> Project Structure -> Platform SDKs -> SDKs -> Add Android SDK from the Android home directory)

Still the error persists. Am I doing it right? Any help?

Comment: Not sure why you need to do that. You just install from the Plugin window

Comment: I am developing a plugin myself, and adding the dependency in plugin.xml

Comment: OK, well `android.jar` is the Android SDK, not the Intellij plugin

Answer (score 1):

> you need to add **plugins/android/lib/android.jar** to the classpath of your IntelliJ IDEA SDK

You've copied the API 25 Android SDK, not Intellij plugin